# Friction forces on stack of blocks

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

Consider a block sliding on a surface, with friction between the two. The friction force will be equal to $\mu N$, where $N$ is the normal reaction force, which is usually equal to $mg$, where, $m$ is the mass of the block. Therefore, the friction force if $\mu m g$

Consider now that I place a second block, of mass $M$, on top of the previous one. The mass of the whole system will now be $m+M$.

My question is what happens to the friction force between the lower block and the ground in this case. Does it remain the same, or does it change to $\mu(m+M)g$?

Comment: If the block is sliding yet, then the friction force will change to it.

Answer (score 1):

The friction force is given by $F_f$ = $\mu$N. In this example, $\mu$ remains the same, while both the normal force and force of friction increase. The normal force is given by $F_n$ = mg. Your confusion arises from what defines m. I like to think of it as "effective mass." Basically, anything that contributes to the interface the friction is acting on. 
So yes, the normal force becomes (M + m)g.

If you are still interested, you can even extend this to fluids. The previous method of thinking about "effective mass" will help you intuitively grasp pressure forces in fluid being simply a function of density, instead of volume. We can even calculate the pressure applied to the system from the gas in the atmosphere above it! Read more on it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure).

Comment: welcome to physics.SE and thank you for sharing your knowledge!